# Find the probabilities of selling at least $n$ items using binomial distribution

Tags: probability

On average, 6 out of 15 customers buy a service plan. You expect to receive 100 customers tomorrow. Find the probabilities that you will sell: at least 1, at least 2, at least 3, ...., at least 20 service.

I used Excel to do `=BINOMDIST(A2,100,40%,TRUE)` then subtracted 1-answer but the numbers seem very off, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Write the probability distribution function (PDF) of a binomial distribution with probability of success = $6/15$ ($40\%$), then sum the PDF up to a candidate value $n$ and then take 1.0 - that value.

Your answer should look like this:

[image]